# Validation Rule - using multiselect picklist

Tags: validation, validation-rule, multi-select

Im trying to write my first validation rule.

1. If 'fruit' is one of the selections from (multi select) picklist A.
2. Display the following fields:

- Apple
- Orange
- Pear

3. Otherwise do not display these fields.

> IF(PicklistA CONTAINS(fruit), Apple AND Orange AND Pear = true)

Can someone advise me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't think you need a validation rule here. A validation rule prohibits a user from saving invalid data, not what information is displayed in the UI.

Comment: ah ok - how can I control whether fields are displayed? if a validation rule is not suitable

Comment: the relevant formula operator is INCLUDES for multi-select picklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via `Custom Lightning record page` with `component visibility` feature for your custom object which has the fields `Piclist A` and `Apple`, `Orange`and `Pear`.

You can refer this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_recordpage) which will help you to done this.

Please let me know if it helps.